# On the subcategory of product-preserving functors

Tags: ct.category-theory

A well-known theorem of Freyd and Kelly says that the subcategory of functors $F : A \to Set$ that commute with a prescribed class of limits is reflective inside the whole $[A,Set]$.

The proof of this statement relies on an application of the small object argument: for a functor $F : A \to Set$ the following conditions are equivalente:

1. $F$ preserves binary products;
2. $F \in \{g\}^\perp$, where $g : A(X,\_\ )\sqcup A(Y,\_\ ) \to A(X\times Y; \_\ )$ is (induced by) the image under Yoneda of the terminal cone $X \leftarrow X \times Y \to Y$.

Of course, the same equivalent conditions apply to more general shapes of diagrams! $F$ preserves all limits of diagrams of shape $\Gamma \subset \sf Cat$ if and only if $F$ is right orthogonal to the set $\{\text{colim } A(\gamma,\_\ ) \to A(\lim\gamma, \_\ ) \mid \gamma \in\Gamma\}$.

Now, the SOA entails that there is a chain of endofunctors $R_\alpha : [A,Set] \to [A,Set]$ that "eventually" fall into $[A,Set]_\times$, or $[A,Set]_\Gamma$: this means that a sufficiently large transfinite composition $R^\kappa : [A,Set]\to [A,Set]_\times$ fall into product-preserving, or $\Gamma$-continuous, functors.

I have no problem with this theorem, apart its complete lack of explicitness:

> How can I get a more concrete description of what is the universal product-preserving functor $\tilde F$ associated to $F$ under the reflection $[A,Set]_\times \leftrightarrows [A,Set]$?

Comment: I think the small object argument is the most explicit you can get in full generality. But I disagree with you that it 'completely lack explicitness': it presents $\widetilde{F}$ as a colimit of an explicitly constructed $\omega$-chain. Of course there are special cases where you can get a better description, for example, if this localization happen to be left exact, or if you have a good understanding of the category $[A,Set]_\times$, as you question boils down to computing colimits in it.

Comment: Thank you. My question stems from the particular case when $A$ is a Lawvere theory; is it possible to say something more in that particular case, when $A$ is such a concrete object?